# pycharm code autocomplete work only in python console but not on python file

Tags: python, pandas, autocomplete, scikit-learn, pycharm

I'm using pycharm IDE, and several libraries such as scikit-learn and pandas. For some reason, if I create a new python file and do:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
pd.   #no auto complete here
```

right after i type **pd.** auto complete doesn't seem to work. I'm getting nothing.
However, if i run a python console within PyCharm, and do similar thing above, the console would pop up an autocomplete window showing all the members of **pd.**.

how do i get autocomplete to work on the main python file?

Comment: Is Runtime-Type-Detection enabled? (`Preferences->Python Debugger->"Collect run-time types information for code insight"`)

Comment: i think it wasn't done "indexing" or whatever. It seems to work fine now. I should've been more patient.

Comment: @Leistungsabfall The auto completes is not working in IDE but it is working in PyCharm's Python Console. I did restart my PyCharm and freshly opened my folder as new project. Nothing works!! I don't know how it suddenly breaks.

Comment: @Leistungsabfall: I enabled that option but did not get autocompletion for scikitlearn and other 3rd party packages that I installed. Do you think I need something else? Thanks!

Comment: Is this question resolved? I fall in the same swamp now...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I import modules in pycharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885821/how-do-i-import-modules-in-pycharm)

Answer (score 3):

I used to have this same problem. This was only happening for me in Linux. (I am using python 2.7)

I have since been able to fix it, I think what did it was defining the correct interpreter not only in the running/debugging configuration, but also in the defaults of the project (check File-->settings-->Project Interpreter and File-->default settings-->Project Interpreter)

I have now moved to the next problem, which is that auto-complete works for Python Console and File editing, but weirdly enough does not work for Debugging!...

Comment: Ah that's correct. I had a mixed project with python3 and python2 source code. And I assumed it would use auto completion of the currently configured run profile. Thx

Answer (score 0):

### Never name project script `numpy.py` identical to package name `numpy`

This is just one possibility that causes autocompletion to fail for only one package: If you by accident name a project script identical to a package name, e.g. creating a python script `numpy.py` in your project and try to `import numpy` then pycharm will refer to your project script in autocompletion instead of to the package `numpy`.

This normally rather happens when using less common packages with more unknown names or e.g. a script name like `code.py` which will break autocompletion due to the package `code`.