# PyCharm how to include wxPython library path/Can I download wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython, pycharm, pypi

I've tried so many times to find this pathing but to no avail(link: [How do I import modules in pycharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885821/how-do-i-import-modules-in-pycharm))
I think it's because I'm using a newer version of PyCharm, but here is my project Interpreter: [image: My project interpreter]

I don't see the + path anywhere in here, and I have downloaded a version of wxPython on my computer that I want to wire the path to. In the url link's first answer, he says to add a path, but I don't even see the path tab in my default settings.

I tried downloading wxPython using the project interpreter, but this is what I get:
[image: Error]

And I searched for a while to find out that perhaps PyPi does not support wxPython(maybe I'm wrong on this, but: https://github.com/kliment/Printrun/issues/535 ,here it says to download the wxPython binary instead because the project interpreter does not support wxPython). I was able to successfully download numpy and matplotlib, so I was quite confused when I couldn't download wxpython.

So now I'm stuck, because I can't add a path to my wxPython(inside of wxMac folder), and I can't download wxPython directly. The only other way I can think of is manually copying and pasting the wxmac folder into my virtualenv folder's bin, but I'm afraid of not copy pasting the right thing into the right directory.

What is going on? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just download the appropriate wxPython binary for your OS and install it that way instead of using PyCharm. I have had no problems installing wxPython on Windows, Linux or Mac doing it this way.

wxPython is currently not on PyPI. The beta version of wxPython, known as wxPython Phoenix, supports [pip](http://wiki.wxpython.org/How%20to%20install%20wxPython#Installing_wxPython-Phoenix_using_pip). The regular version of wxPython (classic) uses just binaries or you can build from source. Note that wxPython Phoenix doesn't have all the widgets that Classic does. It just has the core widgets plus a number of others. You can read more about Phoenix here:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/ProjectPhoenix
- http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/MigrationGuide.html

Comment: Hi, I have tried to download wxPython binaries for my OS, and I believe it was successfuly downloaded under usr/local/cellar/wxmac. However, I don't know if I should copy paste the entire wxmac folder or its smaller folders inside into the virtualenv's lib/python3.4/site-packages/ folder where numpy and PIL/pillow and matplotlib were saved in. I did just that, and I checked pyCharm after restarting and it still gave me the error of "could not find module". I couldn't find very specific instructions on which files to relocate - any ideas?

Comment: Phoenix is the only version of wxPython that is supported for Python 3.4. So you should be able to use the pip link I provided to install it directly in your virtualenv.

Comment: download page doesn't contain safe download options