# PyCharm + conda + pip packages not recognized

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pulp

I can say I am quite new to the world of Python but not to programming. I have been using PyCharm over the last year and I got Python conda distribution to make my life easier with package management.

Lately, I have been trying to play with a package known PuLP which was not available to download via conda but I installed using pip. I realized that although PyCharm recognizes pulp when running my code, it is not in the available packages and I am not sure that the same version of PuLP is used in and out of PyCharm. Specifically, when I run the pulpTestAll command that looks for installed solvers from my terminal, the recognized solvers are different than those recognized when I run exactly the same script within PyCharm.

Can someone give me a tip on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

[How do I import modules in pycharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885821/how-do-i-import-modules-in-pycharm)

You may look here. Maybe you have to specify an interpreter for the Conda environment. To do that when you are choosing an interpreter at the right there is a gear at the right. After you press it, you may add a new interpreter and you can choose Conda Environment.