# How can I make a package from my PyCharm project available to other PyCharm projects on my computer?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am not sure if this is a Python or a PyCharm question. I think that it is quite simple, but I could not find a solution anywhere.

I have started to write a collection of modules with utility stuff. Now I want to import one of my packages in several of my other projects. What do I have to do to be able to simply write `import my_module`, so that Python finds the right one automatically?

I would like to set this up on a Mac and a PC, so advice on both platforms is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I import modules in pycharm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885821/how-do-i-import-modules-in-pycharm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not pyCharm issue. You have to give python information of the place your module live, to do that update `PYTHONPATH`, if you're using bash (OS X,GNU/Linux distro), add this to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/my_module"
```

Also you can checkout that article [How do I set PYTHONPATH](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469160-How-do-I-set-PYTHONPATH-and-other-environment-variables-for-Canopy-)  and SO [How to use PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917492/how-to-use-pythonpath) question to get more info.

To avoid duplicating answer adding a link to give info of how to update PYTHONPATH on Windows: [How to add to the pythonpath in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7?answertab=votes#tab-top)

After you should be able to import your module.

Comment: Wow, I can even modify the search paths at runtime. https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sys.html?highlight=sys.path#sys.path

Comment: sure,you can :) But likely you have to do it in each package, where you are going to import your module,  in other turn PYTHONPATH would work for all packages at once...

Comment: Right, and PyCharm cannot "see" the module content, so there is no autocompletion...