# Nltk Import Error - Cannot import name 'overridden' (Only in PyCharm)

Tags: python, nltk

When importing NLTK via PyCharm (import nltk) I am getting the following error message: ImportError: cannot import name 'overridden'

I can import without a problem via the command prompt.

Using 32-bit python 3+ and Windows 10.

I've tried several fixes including PYTHON PATH and can't seem to find a solution.

Any thoughts on what could be going wrong here?

Comment: Maybe this might help https://gist.github.com/alvations/0ed8641d7d2e1941b9f9

Comment: Went through all of the steps. No help either. Is there a way to overwrite all previous downloads of python and nltk and reinstall all of it as if it never existed?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19885882/610569

Comment: Thanks all. Wound up getting in to work by having windows erase all applications on my computer and then reinstalling.