# Import error for Python custom modules in Pycharm

Tags: pycharm

For some reasons, I can't import my own modules in this format `import module`.

IDE: Pycharm, Python version: 3

files:

```
projectname/scr/test1.py
projectname/scr/test2.py
```

test1.py:

```
def print_value(x)
    print x
```

test2.py:

```
import test1

 value = 5
 test1.print_value(value)
```

Pycharm Editor shows me the following error.

```
import test1 # Error: No module named test1
```

However, when I run the code `(python test2.py)`, it works fine. The only problem is that I do not get recommendations for test1 functions or variables such as when I type test., nothing pops up as a suggestion. It's a bit weird behavior from pycharm.

However, if I move these files up the order in the folder hierarchy, then everything works fine, no errors and proper suggestions are given when I type test1.something.

files:

```
projectname/test1.py
projectname/test2.py
```

Any explanation to this? Why doesn't it work in src folder?

**Update**:
Resolved the issue by marking the `src` as `root sources` inspired by this StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885821/how-do-i-import-modules-in-pycharm). I still do not understand why it happened and why setting this directory as root source resolve this issue but it works for now.

Comment: __init__.py is available in scr?

Comment: @Sosel yes, it's available in src folder.

Comment: what's in sys.path when you run test3.py? Also, it's __init__.py, not init.py

Comment: sorry, \_\_init\_\_.py

Comment: @holak we just wrote it init.py as a short notation. In the src, it is __init__.py.

Comment: @engr_s yes, by bad, I noticed it later that the underscores were replaced to format text. Anyway, have you tried to run test3.py from the command line using import test1, test2 only? Perhaps for some reason Pycharm doesn't add the module's folder in sys.path when it runs it (check its content)

Comment: @holak the command line import for these files also do not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by marking the src as root sources inspired by this StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885821/how-do-i-import-modules-in-pycharm). I still do not understand why it happened and why setting this directory as root source resolve this issue but it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

modules located in same location should be imported without any issue

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'projectname/scr')
from test1 import anything
```

I think, this helps you. By inserting this path to avaliable paths at index 0, you might easily call your module.