# PyAudio not installing in PyCharm on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, pyaudio

I am trying to install PyAudio for a project that I am working on, but when I try to install PyAudio through PyCharm, it comes up with this error. How do I fix this?

[image: error]

Comment: Did you read the error? It's saying you are using Python 2.7. You should not use Python 2.7 anymore. Search for solutions on how to install pyaudio on mac using Python 3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install pyaudio on mac using Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33851379/how-to-install-pyaudio-on-mac-using-python-3)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble installing 'pyaudio' in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47136471/2745495)

Answer (score 0):

Your python version is maybe older ,for older python versions the pyaudio is not supported ,so just update your python and then your good to go

Comment: How do I do that? Do I change the interpreter?

Comment: @BGaming [Configure a Python interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#interpreter)

Comment: I have followed the "How to install pyaudio on mac using Python 3" link but now I can't import modules, like os, gtts, speech recognition, datetime, etc.

Comment: Can you pls explain your problem briefly

Comment: @sHegade I followed the steps in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33851379/how-to-install-pyaudio-on-mac-using-python-3 and got pyaudio installed on python 3.9, but now i cannot import other modules like os, speech recognition, datetime and others.

Comment: I suggest you to use vscode for python,cuz it's beginner friendly ,and automatically detects the python interpreter, and also you can switch between multiple interpreter within single click

Comment: Just try to reinstall your python interpreter ,if this will not be worked then,use python 3.8.6 .and use vscode