# How can i install pyaudio on MacOS

Tags: installation, pip, subprocess, pyaudio

When running the command: "pip3 install pyaudio", I get this error:

```
"Collecting pyaudio
Using cached PyAudio-0.2.14.tar.gz (47 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) did not run 
successfully.
 │ exit code: 1
 ╰─> [18 lines of output]
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/pyaudio
  copying src/pyaudio/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/pyaudio
  running build_ext
  building 'pyaudio._portaudio' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/src
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/src/pyaudio
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DMACOS=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/opt/homebrew/include "-I<PATH FROM STEP 3>/include/" -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c src/pyaudio/device_api.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/src/pyaudio/device_api.o
  src/pyaudio/device_api.c:9:10: fatal error: 'portaudio.h' file not found
  #include "portaudio.h"
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
  1 error generated.
  error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
  [end of output]
```

Note: This error originates from a subprocess and is likely not a problem with pip.

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyaudio, which is required to 
install pyproject.toml-based projects"
```

I am running MacOS 14.3.1 (with Intel chip).
Any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48484173/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/33821084/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/73930804/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpyaudio%5D+fatal+error%3A+portaudio.h+file+not+found

Answer (score 1):

You should first install portaudio through brew:

```
brew install portaudio
pip3 install pyaudio
```

Comment: the first command works, the second gives me the same error yet again

Comment: What about this?

`xcode-select --install`
`brew remove portaudio`
`brew install portaudio`
`pip3 install pyaudio`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33851379/how-to-install-pyaudio-on-mac-using-python-3

Comment: those commands dont work either...same issue

Comment: The next option is `CFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/include -L/opt/homebrew/lib" python3 -m pip install pyaudio`

Comment: same error...i went through these other forums before i submitted my question

Comment: Ok it worked for me with the first two commands on MacOS 14.1.1 . The last thing I see you might have already tried is `pip install --global-option='build_ext' --global-option='-I/usr/local/include' --global-option='-L/usr/local/lib' pyaudio`

Comment: not working...get the same error