# Pycharm not recognizing package that shell does recognize. Django

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I have installed a package, django_celery_beat. I can import it in the shell:

```
>>import django_celery_beat
>>
```

But Pycharm shows me an error, it underlines the import as if the package wasn't installed. Why could this be?

Comment: You probably use virtualenv. To change interpreter path in pycharm open settings>project>project interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyCharm doesn't use `bashrc`, so it doesn't know where your library is. So, now

> There are 2 options:

- Either you should add your own paths for libraries in **Interpreter Paths** list in pycharm

**OR**

- Install package using pycharm

#### Adding Path

- Go into Settings -> Project Settings -> Project Interpreter.
- Then press configure interpreter, and navigate to the "Paths" tab.
- Press the `+` button in the Paths area. You can put the path to the module you'd like it to recognize

You can follow the [link to add path in pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885821/how-do-i-import-modules-in-pycharm) from here.

Comment: How do I add my own path to Interpreter Paths? where is that option/