# set PYTHONPATH enviroment varable for library, but can not import in windows

Tags: python, environment-variables, pythonpath

when I used or write a 3rd party library of python, I want import it in my code file.
In linux set environment variable $PYTHONPATH and works well.
But in Windows, After setting environment variable PYTHONPATH and rebooting,it didn't work. Especially in PyCharm terminal.

Comment: I have sovled this problem by https://stackoverflow.com/a/47561492/7209003

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is specific to PyCharm, I recommend either installing the package into the virtual environment / interpreter you're using for the project from `File - Settings - Project: name - Project Interpreter` or adding the library to your project and setting the folder to be recognised as a source folder by PyCharm.

Right-click the library folder, then select `Mark Directory as - Sources Root`