# I get an ImportError: No module named 'numpy' when trying to use numpy in PyCarm, but it works fine in the interactive console

Tags: python, numpy

1. I'm already installed numpy and it works in cmd.
2. my Python version is 3.7.2 and numpy version is 1.16.0

When I use numpy in windows cmd, It works.
`import numpy` is working well in the python interactive console.
But in pyCharm, it doesn't work and errors with `No module named 'numpy'`.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Read this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885821/how-do-i-import-modules-in-pycharm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably arent using the same python installation in pycharm and in your console. Did you double-check in project settings ?

If you just want to install numpy, you can create a requirements.txt file and add numpy in it, pycharm will suggest to install it if not already done.

Alternatively, you could use a venv

Comment: Thank you for answering!

Comment: I solve it!!
Post it for someone else.

File - Settings - Build, Execution, Deployment - Console - Python Console
And check Python Interpreter without default.

Comment: then I can use numpy.
Thank you

Comment: Yup, you got it :) If my answer helped, please consider upvoting and clicking the accept button :)

Comment: Because by default the when you create the new project in pycharm it creates virtualenvironment along with it if you have selected to do it

Comment: @Gaurav if he installed numpy on the system python, if should have been import-able even in the venv (depending on the venv config, of course)

Comment: @WayToDoor Yes That's what i add at end *If You have selected to do it*