# How to set up python interpreter for pyCharm for Mercurial Hooks

Tags: python, pycharm, mercurial, hook, mercurial-hook

I am very new to Python and am trying to learn it so that I can write Mercurial hooks (https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MercurialApi).

I downloaded PyCharm by Jetbrains with the hope that I could start writing a  python script and have the IDE autocomplete for me so I could see what available functions objects have etc. I started with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from mercurial import ui, hg
# change . to the path to the repo
repo = hg.repository(ui.ui(), '.')

ui.warn('asdfsadf')
```

However, as no Python Interpreter is configured, I can't autocomplete (or, at least that's what I think the issue is). I do have Mercurial installed, and when I do `pip list` I do see the library listed, but PyCharm doesn't know about it. How do I configure thing so that the libraries I want recognized by the IDE get recognized? I know that there are settings which can be set, but I don't understand which ones I want for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this post [How do I import modules in pycharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885821/how-do-i-import-modules-in-pycharm/32911111) helped me a lot to add the appropriate project interpreter.