# Can anyone help me with this PyCharm and Import Modular errors?

Tags: python, macos, pygame, pycharm, pyopengl

So I am trying to run this:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
```

But an error pos up and says:

```
import pygame
ImportError: No module named pygame
```

and sometimes it says this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Abood/Documents/lol.py", line 3, in <module>
    from OpenGL.GL import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OpenGL.GL'
```

**However, this works on IDLE version 2.7.16 and Sublime text, even though I tried changing PyCharm's Settings to python 2.7.16 and added Anaconda.**

I am 13 and new to Coding, anything would help.

Thank you

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885821/how-do-i-import-modules-in-pycharm

Comment: I don't understand what it means and also I tried it and it didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if you have installed pygame module in your Project Interpreter environment.

You can find the environment:

```
  Preferences -> Project:Your Project -> Project Interpreter
```

If you are using anaconda environment, then install the module by running:

```
  conda install -c cogsci pygame
```

Comment: I am trying it now, Thank you anyways

Comment: Wow after 10 hours of trying to solve this Thank and May God Bless you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PyCharm and you want to import new modules in it... 
Open PyCharm click on "File" > "settings" > "Project:Practice" > "Project Interpreter"
then click on "+" sign in the right corner then , search for your module select it and then click on "Install Package" to install.