# Is there any solution if spacy can't be located on my system?

Tags: nlp, spacy, french

As the picture shows, spacy is well installed:

[image: verification]

But I can't still "import" it:

[image: error on Python]

By consulting the official site, it seems that spacy can't be located on my system(win32):

[image: explanation from the official site]

I want to know if there are some solution to it. In fact, I want to use it to treat french corpus, so if it's impossible to profit it, is there any other similar tool I can use to lemmatize french and so on?

Comment: You have 2 different environments: 1 anaconda and another seem to be a PyCharm project. Install spaCy in PyCharm whatever your preferrable method is and you're fine to go.

Comment: I'm sorry, since I'm very green, I really don't know how to install it in IDLE (I have tried pip but failed). And I also tried to use Geany, which didn't work, neither.

Comment: Either follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885821/how-do-i-use-installed-packages-in-pycharm#:~:text=In%20your%20PyCharm%20project%2C%20go,packages%20in%20the%20selected%20env.) or just do `pip install spacy` in your IDE console

Comment: Thanks!!!! Merci énormément !!!! I solved this problem!!! I just can't believe it and wanna cry now!!!! You are such a nice genius.

Comment: PyCharm is awesome and it will increase your productivity in the longer run but you should get accustomed to it