# Unable to install pyodbc and win32API

Tags: python, pycharm, pyodbc

I am using Python 3.9.6 with Pycharm. I need to install the packages pyodbc and win32api. Though I have installed it, reinstalled it multiple times, it still says module not found. I have installed the MS build tools, tried with multiple versions of python such as 3.9.5 and 3.8, restarted pycharm invalidating caches. Changed the interpretes to virtual environment and the system interpreter. When i run the command pip install pyodbc, it says requirement already satisfied which means it is already installed.

Comment: Do you have multiple interpreters

Comment: You've probably installed the package in a different python env. When you did `pip install pyodbc` try getting the python path too - `which python` (in *nix). Your Pycharm is using a different python interpreter

Comment: I installed using the pip command as well as navigating to the settings and selecting interpreter and installing using the + icon. It is working fine for other packages except these two(pyodbc and win32api). I did validate that currently only one version of python exists which is 3.9.5. I am using windows machine

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I recommend that you look at 2 posts, [How do I use installed packages in PyCharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885821) and also [PyCharm doesn't recognise installed module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31235376)

Answer (score 0):

See if pycharm is using another virtual environment

Comment: I have validated and it is pointing to the correct interpreter which has the modules installed.