# PyCharm Virtual Environment Py2app

Tags: python, pycharm, environment, interpreter, py2app

I create small apps and tools for automation. I've been using one project and one interpreter virtual env. (Python 3.9) With bunch of packages like pandas, numpy, Google APIs etc.. Needless to say, I also need to implement version control system (Github).
Would be good to use the same Virtual environment for many projects in this case, since I've been using more or less the same packages for my work. How would this affect py2app?
Associate this  virtual environment with the current project is ticked. If I untick then I can use this environment in another project. Although, I need to know whether this change would affect Py2App.

I'm not a super experienced in terms of this but I need to look under the hood to have the best and smoothest solution.
Many thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use installed packages in PyCharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885821/how-do-i-use-installed-packages-in-pycharm)