# How to import keyboard into pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, pycharm, keyboard

I want to do when "key is pressed"
In pycharm but I cant import keyboard.
I tryed to look on youtube but for them it work but when I try to import keyboard it doesn't exist.
I opened cmd and typed pip instal keyboard and it dawnloaded it and nothing.
Any ideas

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32911111) on how to use installed packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install keyboard package using `pip` package manager from pycharm terminal.

```
pip3 install keyboard
```

Then create inside .py file simply import.

```
import keyboard
```

The terminal should below the Pycharm GUI just like shown in the image.
[image]

Comment: Where do I tipe that pip3 instal keyboard?

Comment: I have add a screenshot please try to follow it.

Comment: Thank you it works i tryed and I needed to upgarde pip than I tryed to update it on python and then when I tryed on cmd as administrator I did something wrong is it said that I need to use other command so I copied it and enter and now it works.

Comment: If you think this answered your question then feel free to upvote and accept it as answer. So that other people can see it. Thanks!